# iOS 13 UIBarButtonItem .close ( X ) tintColor

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, ios13, uiappearance, tintcolor

This might have been answered already but I can't seem to find the answer.

iOS 13 introduces the new UIBarButton.SystemItem value of `.close`.

I have played with the new proxy appearance APIs but no matter what I do the background color for that specific icon (a circle with an X) would not change from a semi-translucent circle with a dark gray X.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .purple` ?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen yes i have :(

Comment: You cannot change it. The background is a separate background image. It is not a template so it is not tinted.

Comment: @matt how about the foreground? the "X" itself? would seem weird that we have to stick on a dark gray regardless of the navigation bar color

Comment: If you want an x in a circle that you can tint, use the symbol image.

Comment: @matt sorry, i just dont get why that one specific UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem wouldnt tint like all others in the enum (i COULD resort to customViews, just dont see the point)

Comment: Complain to Apple, I’ve analyzed this button and I’m just telling you how it is.

Comment: @matt i know :( there has to be an api somewhere (hopefully not private), one of apple's own apps uses that icon on white tint (although my phone is in dark mode right now, but so is my app)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the tintColor, you can override the navigation bar's user interface style to `light` or `dark`, depending on the current theme.

```swift
navigationBar.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tintColor should work except for `UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.close`.

You can use `.stop` instead of `.close` if you want an "x" symbol.